# Assertion error in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am facing following issue in all MongoDB queries:

```
mongoerror: assertion src/mongo/db/storage/extent_manager.cpp:109
```

Please help me to get rid of this issue.

Comment: depending on the mongodb version, you need to look it up in the source code.  any other errors in the log file?

Comment: We need a lot more information. Could you tell us the version and include the full error and relevant surrounding log lines? Can you state precisely what you are doing when the error occurs?

Answer (score 1):

I had the problem. I found out that I had been using 2.4 mongodb database version and when I upgraded to 2.6 it was still using the old data directory. Once I created a new data directory it worked. Hopefully this will work for you..

Comment: But i don't want to loose old data. any solution on that?